# The IsFocused property does not work for ListView in WPF? How can i change the border color of ListView when i press tab or click on the ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, wpf-style

I am designing a ListView and I want to change its border color when it is focused, IsFocused property dosen't seem to work for ListView. Is there any property similar to IsFocused for Listview?

```
 <Style x:Key="{x:Type ListView}" TargetType="ListView">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource EnabledListViewBorder}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
                    <Border x:Name="Border"
                            Background="Transparent"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            BorderBrush="{StaticResource EnabledListViewBorder}"
                            BorderThickness="1">
                        <ScrollViewer Style="{DynamicResource ListViewColumnHeaderScrollViewer}">
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="False" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DiabledListViewBorder}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DiabledListViewBorder}" />
                        </Trigger>                      
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="GotFocus">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard Duration="0:0:0:1" AutoReverse="False">
                        <ColorAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                            FillBehavior="HoldEnd" From="Red" To="Red"/>                        
                    </Storyboard>                    
                </BeginStoryboard>                
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="LostFocus">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard AutoReverse="False" Duration="0:0:0:1">
                        <ColorAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                            FillBehavior="HoldEnd" From="Green" To="Green"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

I have updated the question with my Sourcecode with the solution provided but the  Border Color isn't changing. What am i missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Style.Triggers` to handle `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` events.

```
<ListView.Style>
    <Style TargetType="ListView">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="GotFocus">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard Duration="0:0:0:1" AutoReverse="False">
                        <ColorAnimation 
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                        FillBehavior="HoldEnd" From="Red" To="Red"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="LostFocus">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard AutoReverse="False" Duration="0:0:0:1">
                        <ColorAnimation 
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                        FillBehavior="HoldEnd" From="Green" To="Green" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListView.Style>
```

**Update:**
If you have rewritten the `ControlTemplate`, then delete `Style.Triggers` part and move EventTriggers from it to the `ControlTemplate.Triggers`. Additionally you have to set Storyboard.TargetName="Border".

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="LostFocus">
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard AutoReverse="False" Duration="0:0:0:1" Storyboard.TargetName="Border" >
            <ColorAnimation
Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
FillBehavior="HoldEnd" From="Green" To="Green" />
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>
```

Comment: It will work only if user select one of the item! Nice.

Comment: It works also if you set focus with keyboard. What do you need else? It's exactly what OP wants.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, However it isn't changing the border color, I have edited my question with source code, Can you please tell me what needs to be changed?

Comment: Sure, since you have set another ´ControlTemplate´.

Comment: ''{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}' is not a valid value for property 'BorderBrush'.' There is this wierd error which i get after some seconds.

Comment: I checked in other system, It does not crash with that error, works fine.

Comment: I guess there is some other issue.

Answer (score 0):

For ListBox IsFocused not working because focus goes to ItemsPresenter that contains ListBoxItems. So focus go to ItemsPresenter that is inside the ListBox. I got workaround that you subscribe event MouseDown and inside it do Focus for ListView, then the trigger starts working.

Let me know if it works for you